# Preload or Live Frequent Registry Read and Write

Tags: c#

I am using the registry to store some (20+) data values like window location & size to start with. I am curious if you should preload all of the keys from the registry instead of live query them when a GET or SET is called on a variable. Are there risks to querying or writing data to the registry frequently?

Code example:

```
internal int MainWindowHeight
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                using (RegistryKey mykey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("xxxxx"))
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(mykey.GetValue("xxxx"));
                }
            }
            catch
            { return 0; }
        }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                using (RegistryKey mykey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("xxxxx", true))
                {
                    mykey.SetValue("xxxx", value, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                }
            }
            catch
            {}
        }
    }
```